# Defined color of page rgb

Tags: color

How to defined the color to use it as pagecolor with rgb? This code would work with blue instead of myblue. Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{201.0, 227.0, 248.0}
\pagecolor{myblue}


\begin{document}

ggfhgdg

\end{document}
```

Comment: to convert from RGB to rgb simply divide each number by 255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{201, 227, 248}
\pagecolor{myblue}
\begin{document}

    ggfhgdg

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

rgb takes values between 0 and 1, perhaps you want RGB which takes integer values 0-255 (but in that case you do not want the .0 in the values

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{201, 227, 248}
\pagecolor{myblue}


\begin{document}

ggfhgdg

\end{document}
```